# uninitialized constant Motion::Project::Config::Rake

Tags: rubymine, rubymotion

I'm getting this error after upgrading rubymotion.

```
/Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Anthony/dev/mytrip_ios/Rakefile
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/config.rb:26:in `<class:Config>': uninitialized constant Motion::Project::Config::Rake (NameError)
from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/config.rb:25:in `<module:Project>'
from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/config.rb:24:in `<module:Motion>'
from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/config.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Anthony/dev/mytrip_ios/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my rake file starts like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
require 'rubygems'
```

whats wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

"from /Users/Anthony/dev/mytrip_ios/Rakefile:3:in `'"

Since you are using Ruby > 1.9, you do not need to require rubygems in general.

Furthermore, rubymotion does not handle 'require' statements like regular ruby.

Please take a look at the motion-bundler gem if you are interested in loading ruby classes and extensions from the standard library.